# Exclude one url from rewrite condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following mod_rewrite rule to redirect from site.com to www.site.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] .
```

I need to exclude from this rule urls starting with /yandex_market

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yandex_market.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] .
```

But rule still works on urls starting with /yandex_market How to fix it?

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?yandex_market [NC]`

Comment: Did you test in a different browser? Are there more rules?

Comment: hjpotter92, No effect. anubhava, Does't work in all browsers. I have another rules below this rule.

Comment: @anubhava, this for example: `RewriteRule ^yandex_market/(.+)$ index.php?module=YandexPurchaseView&type=$1  [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your 2nd rule rewrites `/yandex_market/foo` URI to `/index.php?module=YandexPurchaseView&type=foo` and thus making `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yandex_market.*$ [NC]` condition succeed. You will need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable for your condition which doesn't change with application of rewrite rules.

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/yandex_market [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^yandex_market/(.+)$ index.php?module=YandexPurchaseView&type=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```